# Javascript replace function in same field

Tags: javascript, html, replace, onclick

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="text" value=""><br>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {

var str = document.getElementById("text"); 
var res = str.replace("1", "2");
document.getElementById("text") = res;


}
</script>
```

in input field i am taking some input from user on (click) submit i want to replace all 1 with 2 and i want to display result in same field but its not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value

```
function myFunction() {
    //getElementById returns dom object
    var el = document.getElementById("text");

    //you want to replace its value
    var str = el.value;

    //use a simple regex to replace all instances
    var res = str.replace(/1/g, "2");

    //set the value property of the target element
    el.value = res;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gjbabf8y/), [short version](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gjbabf8y/3/)

Comment: Perfectly Working ...Thanks But i Have 1 More lil Question i want to replace [img] as <img src="

Comment: what should be the value of `src=`

Comment: can be something like `'some text [img] with image'.replace(/\[img\]/g, '<img src="" />')`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
function myFunction() {
  var inputElt = document.getElementById("text");
  var res = inputElt.value.replace("1", "2");
  inputElt.value = res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

`document.getElementById("text") = res;`

instead, should look like this:

`document.getElementById("text").value = res;`